# Why do I get Unbound Local Error?

Tags: python

So the functions in question are very long, so I will summarize it.

```
def func1( X = None, Y = None ) :
  if X :
    dostuff
      if condition :
        Z += 1
  if Y :
    print Y

func1.Z = 0

def func2( A )
  for loop that does stuff and calls func1
```

When I run this, it tells me that the line Z += 1 has an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Z' referenced before assignment"

I've read all the Unbound Local Error and Referanced before assignment questions I could find already, but none of the problems seem similar, and none of the solutions work.

Should I just make Z a global?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because setting an attribute on a function object does **not** create a local name. Reference it on the function object within the function too:

```
func1.Z += 1
```

or make it a global. Better still, avoid such shenanigans and just make `Z` a local or a function argument, and return `Z` at the end of the function to the caller.

Comment: Ah! I had no idea. Out of curiousity, would self.Z have worked as well? I'll select this as answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin: Nope. `self` is not the function; `self` isn't anything at all here.

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html# Look here to understand a bit more about python names and values. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is a good description.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin: No; there is no `self` parameter here; this is an attribute on the function object (everything in Python is an object); as there is only one copy of the function, that is essentially global.